# Slick Slider Carousel not showing slides at the start and scrolling is always different

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby, slick.js

I am trying to "implement" slick-slider in **React** like this:
[image: Working Slick Slider]

I am building a site through Gatsby, don't know if that is important information, but will include it just in case.

But when I develop a site through Gatsby this is the type of behavior I get:
[image: Non-Working Slick Slider 1]
[image: Non-Working Slick Slider 2]
[image: Non-Working Slick Slider 3]

Take a careful look at how different selected slide doesn't always move in correct margin. It is always different/moves more and more to the right.

This is part of my code with Slick Slider settings:

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  const settings = 
  {
    className: "center",
    centerPadding: "60px",
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    swipe: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 850,
      settings: 
      {
        centerMode: false,
      },
    },],
  };

  return (
    <Page>...
```

And this is the part where I try to render the slider:

```
<div className="activities">
  <div className="z">
    <div className="activities-container">
      <h1 className="title title-light no-margin">
        ...
      </h1>
      <p className="container-fluid block1-paragraph activities-paragraph">
        ...
      </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <div>
           <img className="slide-img" src={jedan} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={dva} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={tri} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={cetiri} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={pet} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={sest} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={sedam} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={osam} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={devet} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img className="slide-img" src={deset} alt="" />
        </div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I left all of the **divs** the slider is just in case the problem isn't the slider itself.

What is the cause of this issue? Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandbox?

Comment: I cannot make it to run :/

Comment: It seems a CSS issue to me, but without a testing environment (CodeSandbox) it's difficult to guess

Comment: Will play around a bit in CSS to see if something fixes it. Will also try to post CodeSandbox if I manage to make it work